# Rails Observers, Plugins and Migrations are in a race, who wins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-migrations

We just added a couple of observers to our Rails application. Now, when running migrations from scratch we get an error saying that a table doesn't exist (duh, we haven't migrated yet). The error is thrown because a plugin in a model is being loaded that asks for column_names.

I am assuming that the observers are causing the models to be loaded because when we comment out the observers line in application.rb, the error is not thrown.

How do I run migrations without loading observers and models?

or

How do I ask for the column_names in my plugin in a way that won't throw an error when running migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a decent way to disable Observers at run time. This has been previously discussed in [Simple way of turning off observers during rake task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707615/simple-way-of-turning-off-observers-during-rake-task)

However, I guess you could "unplug" the plugin code from your model by redefining the troublesome model in your migration:

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migraation
  class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base; end

  def self.up
    ...
  end

  def self.down
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Going back and tweaking all of my migrations probably isn't a good way forward, but thanks for the link to the other question.

Comment: The link actually provided this awesome fix for the config:


config.active_record.observers = :my_model_observer unless File.basename($0) == 'rake'

Comment: It is not a way of disabling observers at run time, but yes, I didn't realize it might be just a good solution in your situation.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 3 you can skip adding the observers by determining if Rake is being run:

```
config.active_record.observers = :my_model_observer unless File.basename($0) == 'rake'
```

This turns off the observers, which means the models and plugins aren't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can catch the specific exception generated when you run migrations.

Comment: I might catch the exception in the plugin, but definitely not the model.

Comment: I dont think i understood well, what do you mean by "a plugin in a model is being loaded that asks for column_names", where is the column_names method called ? and btw what plugin is it ?

Comment: We wrote the plugin, it isn't public. Part of what it does is check to see if the Model that includes it has specific columns.

Comment: Ok, so in the plugin you can check if the table exists before calling column_names, something like  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.include?(table_name), you can encapsulate this in a table_exists? method in your plugin.

Comment: Humorously table_exists? Already exists as part of ActiveRecord::Base. The issue isn't whether or not it exists or not. The plugin should not be loaded while doing migrations. I am trying to avoid a check because I want it to fail noisily if the table or column doesn't exist.