# Is it possible to check the rails environment for what rake task is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jrubyonrails

Is there an environment variable I could leverage in my rails initializers to determine if a rake task is executing ? Like -- `rake db:migrate db:seed`

I have a bunch of initializers that could be skipped for most rake tasks:

- Don't load spring (it's a jruby project)
- Don't load the audit observer that breaks the migration

Update:

I'm probably going to regret this later -- but the following seems to work --

In my application.rb -- have added the following:

```
config.is_rake = (File.basename($0) == 'rake')
```

Then I am checking for the value later on

```
config.active_record.observers = :audit_observer unless config.is_rake
```

Elsewhere in my spring initializer

```
SPRING_CONTEXT = org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.new(SPRING_XML_CONFIG_FILES) unless Rails.application.config.is_rake
```

Based on answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707615/simple-way-of-turning-off-observers-during-rake-task/4356137#4356137)

Comment: i'm not sure what to do in stack overflow land -- i'm satisfied with my implementation -- do I answer this? delete it ?

Comment: Leave it for someone to find later.

Comment: +1 We had a similar need. And, I think this config.is_rake will be a good start. We also have Spring and don't want it to start during rake tasks, but more specifically things like asset compilation or in rails console.