# Prevent sending emails while db:seed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have an **observer** for a model so every time a new one is created it automatically sends a notification **email**.
The fact is, that every time I **deploy** on heroku, and reset the database, it sends a bunch of emails when creating those models...

Is there a way to prevent email sending from an observer during the "db:seed"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different methods in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707615/simple-way-of-turning-off-observers-during-rake-task) depending on your version of Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your response! As I have more functionality involving the model in that observer, I'll move it to the model's call backs, so I can disable observers and everything works fine.