# Rails ActiveRecord 3.2: How to skip before_delete callback in child model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working in Rails 3.2.16.  In my app, an account has_many users. An account must always have admin users, so you can't destroy them.  This takes care of that:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :check_if_admin

  def check_if_admin
    false if self.is_admin
  end
end
```

However, when you destroy the whole account, the admins should be destroyed as well.  Instead, when I call `@account.destroy` from the controller, the `User#before_delete` callback prevents the admin users from being destroyed.

I know I could call `@account.delete` to skip callbacks, but my understanding is that the `:dependent => :destroy` is itself a callback, so that would only delete the account, not the users.

Is there a way inside the callback to know where I came from, e.g.

```
def check_if_admin
  return if [I'm doing an Account dependent delete]
  false if self.is_admin
end
```

or do I have to manually `delete` the users before `destroy`ing the account?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259681/550712), I found this solution. The idea is to temporarily turn off the specific child callback while destroying the parent. Note that I had to add the `:prepend => :true` option to get my custom callback re-added to the front of the chain.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :disable_user_check_if_admin
  before_destroy :enable_user_check_if_admin

  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy

  def disable_user_check_if_admin
    User.skip_callback(:destroy, :before, :check_if_admin)
  end

  def enable_user_check_if_admin
    User.set_callback(:destroy, :before, :check_if_admin), :prepend => :true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :check_if_admin
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :restrict

  def check_if_admin
    false if self.is_admin
  end
end
```

Without `:prepend => :true`, I ran into trouble because my User model also `has_many :contacts, :dependent => :restrict`. The problem is that, `skip_callback` actually deletes the callback and `set_callback` re-adds the callback *at the end of the callback chain*. Using  `:prepend => :true`, I was able to insert my custom `before_destroy :check_if_admin` callback at the front of the chain. See docs and source code [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set_callback).

**Alternative solution (not in use)**

While I was fighting the callback sequence, I tried a different solution that leaves the callbacks intact. Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/711602/550712), I used an accessor on Account to let me check when it is being deleted:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :disable_user_check_if_admin
  before_destroy :enable_user_check_if_admin

  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessor :destroying

  def disable_user_check_if_admin
    self.destroying = true
  end

  def enable_user_check_if_admin
    self.destroying = false
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :check_if_admin
  has_many :contacts, :dependent => :restrict 

  def check_if_admin
    return if self.account.destroying
    false if self.is_admin
  end
end
```

This did work but it doesn't "smell" right to be setting and checking a flag like this, so I went back to the skip/set callback using `:prepend => :true`.